# node.js jshtml-express layout

Tags: node.js, viewengine

**Hello!**

**Is there any way to have the master page or layout in jshtml?**

I tried do this in .net Razor style, but it did't works.
[Link to jshtml view engine.](http://github.com/elmerbulthuis/jshtml)

My intention is to have mastarpage lets say is called layout.jshtml and some other subpages like index.jshtml and so on, like it is in razor.

More explanation of what I mean speaking "I would like have masterpage"
I have Layout.jshtml , this is my masterpage

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css" ></link>

</head>
<body>

@writeBody();




</body>
</html>
```

and I have other view called some.jshtml

```
<h1>@locals.title</h1>
<div class="Mydata">
@locals.content
@locals.otherContent
</div>
```

When I run this page in browser I would like to have concatenation of layout.jshtml and some.jshtml. The content of some.jshtml is rendered in writeBody(); in layout.jshtml

When I speaking of concatenation I mean someThing like this. This is result that I can see in browser.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css" ></link>

</head>
<body>

<h1>title</h1>
<div class="Mydata">
content
otherContent
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The jshtml repo links to the [jshtml-express](https://github.com/elmerbulthuis/jshtml-express) project.

The docs there give an example of how to use this in your project :

```
var express = require('express');

var port = parseInt(process.argv.pop());
var app = express();
app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(app.router);
});

app.engine('jshtml', require('jshtml-express'));  // make sure you have installed via npm install jshtml-express
app.set('view engine', 'jshtml');
```

I have not used this myself, but the process is similar with other templating systems (Jade, Handlebars, etc).

Comment: Hello Nick, thanks for Your reply, yes i have installed jshtml-express by npm , and add the lines of code You mentioned, furthermore I have ability to run *.jshtml files to show my data.
But I dont know how to setup my app to have masterpage.

Comment: Gotcha, I think i'm a little unclear on what you mean by masterpage. Could you give some more detail on that?

Answer (score 0):

More explanation of what I mean speaking "I would like have masterpage"
I have Layout.jshtml , this is my masterpage

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css" ></link>

</head>
<body>

@writeBody();




</body>
</html>
```

and I have other view called some.jshtml

```
<h1>@locals.title</h1>
<div class="Mydata">
@locals.content
@locals.otherContent
</div>
```

When I run this page in browser I would like to have concatenation of layout.jshtml and some.jshtml. The content of some.jshtml is rendered in writeBody(); in layout.jshtml

When I speaking of concatenation I mean someThing like this. This is result that I can see in browser.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css" ></link>

</head>
<body>

<h1>title</h1>
<div class="Mydata">
content
otherContent
</div>

</body>
</html>
```